# Error during Connect a QuickBooks company file

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have downloaded the sample app from https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/QuickbooksV3API-DotNet. I did the steps upto number 3 successfully in my local system, but when I go to step 4 which is "Connect a QuickBooks company file" I get an error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.". The error is happening in the following line.

**IToken requestToken = session.GetRequestToken();**

Can anyone share some thoughts? Thanks

Comment: What OAuth endpoint are you passing into CreateSession()?  The web.config should have  
    <add key="Url_Request_Token" value="/get_request_token" />
    <add key="Url_Access_Token" value="/get_access_token" />
    <add key="Intuit_OAuth_BaseUrl" value="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1" />

Comment: Also, can you run Fiddler and capture the request/response if it is making a call?

Comment: I am using the exact same values in the web.config that you have specified. The client QB online account that I am trying to connect to is using the old classic version that is not yet upgraded to the new version. So, could this be the reason that it is not working? Thanks

Comment: No, it is not related to the version.  Can you capture the failure in Fiddler?